# Why is the ID property of this query result undefined?

Tags: javascript

This code logs out `[ { ID: 4 } ]`.

```js
const result = await db.query(
  `SELECT ID FROM MetaData WHERE MintStatus='unminted' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;`,
);

thisID = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log(thisID[0]);
```

But if I do `thisID[0].ID` it returns `undefined`. Why?

Comment: Is `[ { ID: 4 } ]` the result of `thisID[0]` or of `thisID`? Arrays don’t have an `ID` property.

Comment: Are you sure that the query returns the data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If this console.log output is correct.

You can get the ID by writing `thisID[0][0].ID`